# Forma eficiente de salvar um objeto File localmente para uso posterior

Tags: javascript, file-upload, localstorage

Olá! Estou desenvolvendo um web app, e nele upload de arquivos são feitos.
 Quando o usuário está off-line (é um PWA) preciso salvar estes arquivos localmente para fazer upload posterior. Não posso salvar um objeto File diretamente no localStorage, então estou usando essa função para converter o conteúdo do arquivo em um array de *bytes*, usar `JSON.stringify` para converter o *array* em uma string JSON e então salvar no localStorage:

```
async function FileToJSONString(file, callback) {
    console.log(file);
    let result =
    await file
    .stream()
    .getReader()
    .read();

    let value = result.value;
    callback(JSON.stringify(value))
}
```

**Problema:**
O problema é que salvar o conteúdo do arquivo dessa forma usa muito espaço e tem um alto custo de desempenho.

**Pergunta:**
Há outra maneira mais adequada de salvar localmente o arquivo? (Não me importo em usar outra forma de armazenamento que não seja o localStorage)

Comment: De onde vem esse `file`? O que ele é?

Comment: Talvez uma opção seja utilizar a API [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).

Comment: @LuizFelipe O file vem de um input de arquivos HTML: `<input>.files`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: @LuizFelipe funcionou perfeitamente com IndexedDB. Grato.